# Many-To-Many relationship data from mysql through Python 3.4 and Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, django-1.8

below is my model. i am using python 3.4 and django 1.8

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    pid=models.IntegerField(db_column='pid')
    loc=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
          managed="false"
          db_table="protbl"

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    pfid = models.ManyToManyField(Profile,db_column='pfid')
    portfolio=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
          managed="false"
          db_table="pfotbl"
```

i would like to search and find the matches to given portfolio item(one or morethan). i tried using the below view but no luck as expect.

my view is:

```
match_res = Portfolio.objects.filter(portfolio='portfoliofilter')
```

-
please direct me to achive.

i am looking the json output in the queryset result itself.

```
[{
    "loc": "Singapore",
    "pid": 10012,
    "portfolio": [{
        "portfolioname": "portfolio1",
        "portfoliorank": "8"
    }]
}, {
    "loc": "Singapore",
    "pid": 10013,
    "portfolio": [{
        "portfolioname": "portfolio2",
        "portfoliorank": "5"
    }]
}
```

]

got the above json structure using the below code but it is taking more than 5 minutes for 1mn records.

```
res=list(match_res.values('loc','pid','__portfolioname','__portfoliorank')) 
match_res_d = [] 
for g, items in itertools.groupby(res['parent'], 
            lambda x: (x['loc'], x['pid'])): 
            items = [{k: v for k, v in item.items() 
if k not in ('loc', 'pid')}for item in items] 
            data.append({ 'loc': g[0], 'pid': g[1], 'child': items })
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're asking how to filter Profiles to return those with the selected Portfolio. You can do this with the double-underscore syntax:

```
match_res = Profile.objects.filter(portfolio__portfolio='portfoliofilter')
```

Comment: Hi Roseman, I got the query set already as per the view logic, I tried to get expected json result - for this I used Iterator and other looping concepts, but it takes huge time to process millions of records.. Could you please guide me to have fastest way for achieving this json result ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking. You haven't shown any iterator or loops.

Comment: i am looking the json output in the queryset result itself (from m-t-m model).

Comment: Then you should show the code you're currently using and the output you get from it.

Comment: below is my code to get the above json format but it is taking   morethan 5mintues to complete 1mn records.     res=list(match_res.values('loc',' pid','__portfolioname','__portfoliorank,..etc))
match_res_d = []
            for g, items in itertools.groupby(res['parent'], lambda x: (x['loc'], x['pid'])):
                items = [{k: v for k, v in item.items() if k not in ('loc', 'pid')} for item in items]
                data.append({ 'loc': g[0], 'pid': g[1], 'child': items })